# Swift ios navigation bar wont appear after hidden by scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

The structure of my VC is `View -> Scroll View -> View` if it matters.

Then I am using this code in order to hide the navigation bar when scrolling occurs. The only problem is once the bar gets hidden it wont show again. There is only a white line visible (Carrier, battery etc).

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
```

So my question now is how do I show the bar again?

Thanks in advance

Edit, apple docs:

*Discussion
When this property is set to true, an upward swipe hides the navigation bar and toolbar. A downward swipe shows both bars again. If the toolbar does not have any items, it remains visible even after a swipe. The default value of this property is false.*

Answer (score 0):

if you are using scrollView then you have to use scrollView delegate function `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView:)` as below with `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()`

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    if translation.y >= 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

}